Why does the est. value of an item in krunker change into unknown?
One of my relic skins in krunker used to have an est. value of 1999 kr or so. However, after a while, the est. value changed to unknown, and it makes people think it is worthless. Why did it change to unknown?


The estimated value of a skin in krunker changes very often. It is mainly due to people on the market who lists this skin. The estimate value is the average KR worth of that skin of the price people listed it for, and people often list the skins for different prices. If people didn't list that skin for a while, the Est. value would become Unknown.

Are you the same person as the user who asked the question? (you have similar looking names).

It looks like you’ve created two accounts somehow.  If you want to merge these accounts please use the Contact link (also found at the bottom of the page).  Select Account Issue and then I need to merge user profiles.
